# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx' from origin 'xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the request

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I've tried all possible settings but still can't fix this. I created my server with express nodejs and deployed it on Heroku. Everything works perfectly on my localHost (server and client), but not when the server is on Heroku.

I was reviewing all the answers on this question on stackoverflow and I still can't solve it ='(

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGO_URL)
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database!');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log('DB Connection failed!');
    
});

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(AUTH, authRoute);
app.use(USERS, userRoute);
app.use(PRODUCTS, productRoute);
app.use(CARTS, cartRoute);
app.use(ORDERS, orderRoute);
app.use(CHECKOUT, stripeRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello to Greensai Updated!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 5000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code right in between app.use(express.json()); and app.use(AUTH, authRoute);

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

This should allow your server to send a response back to the client.

Comment: I added the following, but now I get another error

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT, DELETE, PATCH ");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization, Origin, Accept");
  next();
});

New Error: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response